# Carriage return character missing (Style/EndOfLine) in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

I'm writing an very simple Rails application. It was very simple but I always get an warning message "Carriage return character missing" even if in two examples blow...
Can anyone tell me what is missing and what should I do to resolve this warning message?
I'm using Ruby 2.3.3, Rails 5.1.2 and Rubocop 0.49.1...
[image: Rails router]
[image: Two simple application]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this warning being raised by RuboCop when you run `rubocop` in the terminal?

You might want to try adding this to your `.rubocop.yml`

```
Style/EndOfLine:
  EnforcedStyle: lf
```

If that doesn't work swap try swapping `crlf` for `lf`

via: https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/issues/4293

Comment: I saw it when editing Ruby code is RubyMine, I tried but I was unable to find .rubocop.yml file. Do you know the location of this file? I'm using RubyMine with Windows 8.1

Comment: Yeah I found it. It in C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.3.0\lib\ruby\gems\2.3.0\gems\rubocop-0.49.1\config
Thank you!

Comment: happy to help. fyi `.rubocop.yml` is a file you should create in the root directory (`.`) of your project. Read more here https://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/

Answer (score 0):

My fix was to:

- cut the contents
- delete the file
- re-create the file
- paste the contents back in

Rubocop was not happy with the way rails created the file.

---

In my case, I generated a project with `rails new sample-project --api`

After adding `# frozen_string_literal: true` to the top of `config/seeds.rb`, I got this error:

```
db/seeds.rb:1:1: C: Layout/EndOfLine: Carriage return character missing.
# frozen_string_literal: true ...
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```